# ng-repeat won´t work with my array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I´m a newbie to Angular Js and I´m trying to get the ingredients from an array using ng-repeat on this format:

```
<ng-repeat="ingredient in recipe['_source']['ingridients'] track by $index">{{ ingredient }}
```

The array looks like this:

```
ingredients: 
  Array[6]
    0: "1/4 cup ice"
    1: "1 fluid ounce vodka"
    2: "1/2 fluid ounce Galliano liqueur"
    3: "2 fluid ounces citrus flavored energy drink (e.g. Red Bull™)"
    4: "2 fluid ounces lemon-lime soda"
    5: "1 teaspoon honey"
```

Does someone know the syntax how to reach the objects in the array with that format on the array-variable? I´ve been trying multiple ways to get the objects, but it won´t work.

It works to write out single variables (for example `{{recipe['_source']['name']}}`).

Comment: What does your recipe array actually look like? Can you provide a plunker that shows the issue you are having?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems just a mistype, you have written `ingridients` instead of `ingredientes`. If possible, use actual tags and attributes instead of angular-provided tags.

```
<div ng-repeat="ingredient in recipe._source.ingredients track by $index">
  {{ ingredient }}
</div>
```

Comment: Of course you´re right! My tunnel visioned mind managed to miss that small detail! :). It works with both: recipe._source.ingredients and recipe['_source']['ingredients']. Thank you!

Comment: yes, it's just javascript property access, it's equivalent to say `object.property` and `object['property']` but the first form is neater.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
<ul>
   <li ng-repeat="ingredient in recipe track by $index">{{ ingredient }}</li>
<ul>
```

where your array would look something like

```
var recipe = [
    "1/4 cup ice",
    "1 fluid ounce vodka",
    "1/2 fluid ounce Galliano liqueur",
    "2 fluid ounces citrus flavored energy drink (e.g. Red Bull™)",
    "2 fluid ounces lemon-lime soda",
    "1 teaspoon honey"   
]
```